# Who edited the second edition of Nicola Tesla's autobiography?

Tags: textual-history, nikola-tesla, my-inventions

While reading Nicola Tesla's Autobiography "*My Inventions*" for the second time, I noticed that the book is quite different. Indeed, there seem to be in circulation at least two vastly edited versions: One that mentions The Editors of the *Electrical Engineer* in the third paragraph of chapter one "*My Early Life*", and one that doesn't.

As the topics covered seem to be quite distinct, I'd like to find out more about whether it was Tesla himself who did the editing, which of the two editions is original, and whether it happened posthumously.

Can any information on the subject be found?

Comment: Some information in the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Inventions:_The_Autobiography_of_Nikola_Tesla) mentions several published versions, [including a curious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Inventions:_The_Autobiography_of_Nikola_Tesla#The_Strange_Life_of_Nikola_Tesla) internet version with *numerous omissions and additions*.

Comment: @justCal The recently edited wikipedia page offers great answers to most of my questions above

Answer (score -2):

Per the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Inventions:_The_Autobiography_of_Nikola_Tesla), Ben Johnston was the one who edited the book.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Your answer is rather short and relies on Wikipedia, which is not always reliable. You could significantly improve your answer by finding and adding information from other sources.